# toogle class on click, without having a function for every element

Tags: angular

Lets say I have something like:

```
<div (click)="toggleMe()" [class.toggled]="something"></div>
<div (click)="toggleMe()" [class.toggled]="something"></div>
<div (click)="toggleMe()" [class.toggled]="something"></div>
```

I want to toggle the class on the div I clicked on, however I don't want to create a different variable in the component for each div. How could I solve this?

With jQuery I would do something like this:

```
$("div").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

now this will work for every div, no matter how much I will add. Is there an equivalent to this in Angular? Maybe something like the `this` reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create specific variables for the div elements, you can use the `event.target` property of the `click` event to refer to the HTML element, and toggle the class with `element.classList.toggle("toggled")`:

```
<div (click)="toggleMe($event)">Div1</div>
<div (click)="toggleMe($event)">Div2</div>
<div (click)="toggleMe($event)">Div3</div>
```

```
toggleMe(event: Event) {
  const element = (event.target as HTMLElement);
  element.classList.toggle("toggled");
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3xegxz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: ah great. exactly what I searched.